# My async await method for fetching docs in Firestore using getDocs() returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

My async await method for fetching docs in Firestore using getDocs() returns an empty array.

I'm using **React.js.**
Thing is, this fetching-data-function is placed within a useEffect() hook with an empty array [] as a dependency (so that it runs, and hence fetches data from the Firestore database only *once*), and right after, the data is console logged. Output is an empty array.

```
allData:  []
```

But if I just somehow get the useEffect() hook to run once more (like making a tiny change in the code and saving it - essentially just refreshing it on the local host), the array is populated with the desired data from the database.

This is the code:

```
import db from "./firebase";

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect ran");

    const temp = async () => {

      const q = query(collection(db, "blogs"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const newblog = {
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          content: doc.data().content,
        };

        setAllData((prev) => [...prev, newblog]);
      });

    };

    temp();
    console.log("allData: ", allData);
  }, []);
```

I can't quite figure out what the issue is. I'd be grateful for some help.

Comment: That log statement will always log undefined as Firestore fetches data asynchronously. Instead try rendering the data in the UI directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a empty array in `allData` because the `console.log("allData: ", allData)` is running before than `setAllData((prev) => [...prev, newblog])` because the async function `temp` doesn't run in the same thread so the interpreter continues reading the code that follows. To fix it add `await` to `temp()` like this: `await temp()` and wrap it like I do in the following code.

```
import db from "./firebase";

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("use effect ran");

  (async () => {
    const temp = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "blogs"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const newblog = {
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          content: doc.data().content
        };

        setAllData((prev) => [...prev, newblog]);
      });
    };

    await temp();
    console.log("allData: ", allData);
  })();
}, []);
```